# Is there a way to send packets through one ISP and receive answers through another one?

Tags: networking, routing

I just finished building my first load balancer that combines two different ISPs. This mechanism works just fine, but it's a little bit limited because a connection can't simply utilize both ISP at the same time.

One of the ISPs has a link 15/1 mbit/s and the other 3/20 mbit/s (lte). I'm just wondering if there's a possibility to send packets via one link and receive the answers through the other one. So in the result I would get a link 15/20 mbit/s. Is that possible?

Comment: You might be able to send packets out via ISP 1 with the source address set to your address with ISP 2. Possibly.

Comment: In general: Don't attempt that without having talked to your ISP's. There's a good chance such packets would be dropped somewhere, if it's not the ISP you send the packets through, it would possibly only affect some of your traffic and it would be really hard to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible cases:

1. you have ordered from both ISPs the fixed IPs (or ranges) and you
   made a special arrangement with ISP that handles your outbound
   traffic to allow the traffic from your site that has different
   source IP addresses in IP packets than this ISP provided to you.
   Also, most likely, this ISP would request a proof from you that
   these IP's are assigned to you by another ISP/internet authority.
   Then this is possible.
2. you did not make any arrangements with ISPs in this regard and do
   send the traffic with altered source addresses on your own. Then an
   ISP would block all such traffic. If the ISP is clever enough it
   would block eventually any traffic from your site for suspicious activity (in
   their attempts to combat virus spreading, for example)

**Edit:**

There is the third case that makes possible to get a benefit from splitting the traffic, but it requires you to have a server rented with a flat rate (otherwise, you would pay too much for your traffic) and rented preferably at one of these ISPs (to minimize the latency in one of the directions).

You set up two `VPN`s between your gateway and this server - one using a link to the first ISP and another one to use a link to the second. Then, at this server you masquerade all 'external' traffic and set appropriate routes to handle 'internal' traffic. With some configuration effort using for example [GRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation) encapsulation with fixed keying, you could achieve near-to-zero incoming traffic on your 'outgoing' link and near-to-zero outgoing traffic on your 'incoming' link.